# Finding height of this triangle

Tags: triangles, area

Find $QM$?

[image]

My question is why can't we apply Pythagoras on $\Delta{QMR}$ as it's a right angle triangle?

Comment: If you are saying that $MR=8$ then your triangle is impossible.  The hypotenuse can't be shorter than a leg.

Comment: If "QM is perpendicular to PR" and "$MR=8$ cm" is exactly what the task given then $PL=5$ cm will be pointless.

Comment: You'd need to find the length of $MR$ to do this. Once you have found that, you can definitely apply Pythagoras. But finding that seems just as hard as just finding $QM$.

Comment: @CuriousM3 Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You certainly can apply Pythagoras but you only have one side, the $4$.  The $8$ is the length of $PR$, not the length of $MR$ as $MR \lt 4$

You are expected to compute the area of the triangle from the given base and altitude, then see the $8$ as a base and $QM$ as an altitude.  That will give you $QM$ and then you can use Pythagoras to get $MR$ if you want.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

By similarity of $\triangle PLR$ and $\triangle QMR$ we have

$$\frac{QM}{QR}=\frac{PL}{PR}\implies QM=\frac{PL}{PR}\cdot QR$$

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $\angle PLR$ is a right angle (without which the solution of the problem is not unique),
triangle $\triangle PLR$ is similar to triangle  $\triangle QMR.$
That is,
$$
PR : PL = QR : QM.
$$
Substituting the known quantities,
$$
8 : 5 = 4 : QM.
$$
Solve for $QM.$